# Redshift schema design

Tags: database-design, database-schema, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to design a database schema  which needs to operate on a set of data that looks like this:

```
Events
event_id|time|key1|key2|data
```

And it needs to perform queries like this efficiently:

*Get all events where key1/key2 = ... and time is between ... and ...*

One schema I thought of would be

```
Events
primary_key=event_id|key1|key2|data

Key1Lookup
primary_key=key1|sortkey=time|event_id

Key2Lookup
primary_key=key2|sortkey=time|event_id
```

So that my query might look like

`SELECT data FROM Events, Key1Lookup WHERE key1=... AND time BETWEEN ... AND ... AND Events.event_id = Key1Lookup.event_id`

or

`SELECT data FROM Events, Key2Lookup WHERE key2=... AND time BETWEEN ... AND ... AND Events.event_id = Key2Lookup.event_id`

Does this seem like the right key selection/query design? I'm completely new to redshift, so I really need guidance here.

Additional information:
The event_id is unique.
In Key1Lookup, key1 is not unique, but there are only a few repeats in Key1Lookup (think of it like a user_id in a comments table).
In Key2Lookup, key2 is not unique, but there are only a few repeats in Key2Lookup (think of it like a location_id in a comments table).
There are a huge number of distinct key1s, and there are a huge number of distinct key2s.
I expect the distinct number of key1s to increase a lot, and I expect the distinct number of key2s to increase a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few pointers relevant to what you've mentioned:

- Redshift doesn't really understands primary keys or does any indexing internally. This is what the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html) says.

> Uniqueness, primary key, and foreign key constraints are informational
>   only; *they are not enforced by Amazon Redshift*.

- Redshift stores data in columnar format. So, if your select query doesn't refer to a particular column, all data in that column will be ignored.
- Distribution keys can be used for co-locating joins on two tables. However, there can only be one dist-key in those two tables.

Based on these two, I'd recommend the following:

- Definitely have a sort-key on `timestamp`. So any `between ... and ...` query on `timestamp` will simply skip unnecessary rows.
- If you had only one `key`, you could have used the schema you proposed. `key` would've been the dist-key, because of which your joins (with the `Events` table) would have been very efficient. But can't go that route because you have two keys.
- So, having de-normalized data (`event_id=primary-key|timestamp=sort-key|key1|key2|data`) would be very efficient.

  - It will be better than joining on 3 tables (each of which is going to grow with time) every time.
  - And as I said earlier, if your select query has a condition on only one key (for e.g., `key1=...`), the entire `key2` column will be ignored.

Comment: So the only difference you're proposing is to make event_id the distkey, correct?

Comment: see point #2 above: i said there is no point in having a dist-key in your setup.see point #3: you can put event_id as primary key, if you like.

Comment: my main recommendation is to have denormalized data, as against the normalized one that you have in mind. & i guess i have put enough reasoning behind it